# Is there any "primary" DB in parachain network?

Tags: parachain, parachain-collator

Given the following parachain network setup:

- collator **C0**
- collator **C1**
- bootnode **B0**

C0 and C1 are initial collators that are specified in chain spec (invulnerables).
B0 is the sole bootnode in chain spec and also acts as public rpc-node.

Questions would be:

1. How would they sync with each other if all of their DBs are different? (e.g. when C0 and B0's DB get corrupted while C1 has the valid DB)
2. If I delete C0 and B0's DB, can they start to sync correctly from the beginning?
3. What if I delete C1's DB instead? I assume there's no way to get the correct DB anymore?
4. Is it generally true that as long as there's one node which has the valid DB, the whole parachain network can sync to the correct state eventually? No matter which role this node is (collator/rpc-node/bootnode)? And does the pruning mode matter?
5. How does the parachain network find out the "valid" DB? Given that the relaychain network only records the head state of parachain blocks.

If there's any official documentation about this it would be very helpful!
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Kailai these are great questions. I would recommend you focus in on one question per post or indicate which question is your over-arching question that can represent all the underlying questions you have.

Comment: I see, thanks @Bruno. I'll rephrase it and create new tickets